# Failing to push mpeg dash segment to webdav server using method PUT

Tags: ffmpeg, webdav

I am trying to push mpeg dash segments to webdav server.

Here is the command:

ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -re -i /home/SAFWAN/URI.mp4 -codec copy -sc_threshold 0  -b_strategy 0 -use_timeline 0 -use_template 1 -window_size 10 -init_seg_name init-$RepresentationID$.mp4 -strict -2 -f dash -segment_list_flags +live -min_seg_duration 2000000 -method PUT http://192.168.22.112/webdav/SAFWAN5/manifest.mpd

But I am able to push hls segments using sample ffmpeg command:
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -re -i /home/SAFWAN/URI.mp4 -codec copy -method PUT -f hls http://192.168.22.112/webdav/SAFWAN5/master.m3u8

Here is the apache2 access log:
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:32:28 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/manifest.mpd HTTP/1.1" 200 292 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:32:38 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/chunk-stream0-00004.m4s HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:32:38 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/chunk-stream1-00004.m4s HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:32:39 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/manifest.mpd HTTP/1.1" 200 292 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:32:48 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/chunk-stream0-00005.m4s HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:32:48 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/chunk-stream1-00005.m4s HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:32:49 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/manifest.mpd HTTP/1.1" 200 292 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:32:53 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/chunk-stream0-00006.m4s HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:32:53 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/chunk-stream1-00006.m4s HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:32:53 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/manifest.mpd HTTP/1.1" 200 292 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:32:57 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/chunk-stream0-00007.m4s HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:32:57 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/chunk-stream1-00007.m4s HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:32:57 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/manifest.mpd HTTP/1.1" 200 292 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:33:00 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/chunk-stream0-00008.m4s HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:33:00 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/chunk-stream1-00008.m4s HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"
183.82.0.170 - - [18/Apr/2020:10:33:01 -0400] "POST /webdav/SAFWAN5/manifest.mpd HTTP/1.1" 200 292 "-" "Lavf/57.83.100"

Please let me know why the dash segments is failing to push to webdav server?

Answer (score 0):

I got to know the reason.

Earlier I was using ffmpeg version 3.4.

Updated ffmpeg version to 4.1. It is pushing the segments to webdav server. Also checked the playback.